# geodesic on sphere that passes through the given point and has tangent vector equal to nonzero vector

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, geodesic

Could anyone help with this problem?

On the unit sphere $S$ in 3-D space,
we describe every point on $S$ by its spherical coordinates $(θ,φ)$ . 
Given a point $(θ_1,φ_1)$  on $S$ , and a nonzero vector $p$ on the tangent space to $S$ at $(θ_1,φ_1)$ , determine how to find analytically a geodesic on $S$ that passes through $(θ_1, φ_1)$ and has tangent vector equal to $p$.

Thank you

Comment: You can always use a rotation to make your point the North Pole, and get your tangent vector pointing in a given direction. Then the geodesic is a great circle, and then you can reverse the rotations to have the geodesic pass through your point.